# IE z-index and input button problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have 2 divs(a,b) inside a div(x). so a has z-index 1 and b-2. the page displays fine and only when i hit submit it throws an error saying the object does not support the property and refers to  document.getElementByID('button1').click();

Looks like this is a bug with IE. but I couldn't find any thing concrete to start fixing this problem.

The page is loaded in frames in side a custom portal. Is the problem because the form that the button is trying to submit is not on z-index?

It would be great if some one could guide me to a solution.

Thanks.

css code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
#x { position: relative; }
#a, #b{ position: absolute; left: 25%; }
#a{ z-index:1; }
#b{ z-index:2; }
</style>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that this problem is related to the z-index. Can you post your JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. Looks like it wasn't the problem with z-index or document.getElementByID('button1').click() . It was more of a bug within the proprietary tool i use at my work.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementByID('button1').click();

If the button is hidden or cannot have the focus. you may not be able to call 'click()' like that in some browsers.

Try document.getElementByID('button1').focus(), if you get the same error you'll need to call the handler directly, or move the button up front.